# Deploying Jekyll on Heroku Fails

Tags: ruby, heroku, jekyll

Using Jekyll 2.5.3 on Heroku with Github deployment. Jekyll builds fine locally on OS X, but fails on Heroku. Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated.

**config.ru**

```
require 'rack/jekyll'
require 'yaml'
run Rack::Jekyll.new
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'bundler'
gem 'jekyll', '~> 2.5'
gem 'jekyll-redirect-from', '~> 0.8'
gem 'html-proofer'
gem 'rack-jekyll'
gem 'compass'
```

**app.json**

```
{
  "name":"ninelabs.com",
  "scripts":{},
  "env":{
    "LANG":{
      "required":true
    },
    "RACK_ENV":{
      "required":true
    }
  },
  "addons":[]
}
```

**Here's the log showing errors:**
Note the line `No such file or directory - /apple-icon-72x72.png (Errno::ENOENT)`

```
> 2015-10-04T16:41:32.741506+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rackup config.ru -p 13959`
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.929983+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:102:in `initialize': No such file or directory - /apple-icon-72x72.png (Errno::ENOENT)
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930023+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:102:in `open'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930058+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:102:in `has_yaml_header?'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930076+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:177:in `block in read_directories'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930093+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:172:in `each'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930109+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:172:in `read_directories'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930126+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:151:in `read'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930149+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.5.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:49:in `process'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930174+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-jekyll-0.3.5/lib/rack/jekyll.rb:29:in `initialize'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930192+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `new'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930209+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930225+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930241+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930263+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `new'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930288+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930305+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930321+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930337+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930354+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930371+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930400+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930417+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930434+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:147:in `start'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930451+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930468+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `load'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.930489+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rackup:23:in `<main>'
> 2015-10-04T16:41:37.956751+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration file: /app/_config.yml
> 2015-10-04T16:41:39.069543+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
> 2015-10-04T16:41:39.062775+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: Reverting to Jekyll 1.5 allows the site to build on Heroku. Sadly, 1.5 doesn’t support some of the things we use.

Comment: Issue discovered here: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4011